# Disadvantage of using Hadoop for processing payroll

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloud, distributed-computing

I was asked this question in an interview. The question was asked when I was explaining the disadvantages of Hadoop. 
The disadvantages I told them are:
     1. Single point of failure because of single master nodes.
     2. Security is not at its best.
     3. Suitable for processing only very large data/files.

Now, when I am learning more about the disadvantages, I am confused whether the batch processing nature of the Hadoop that makes it unsuitable for processing payroll at an organisation?
Can you please let me know whether my assumption is correct?
The answer I gave at the interview was completely different. I told them due to the distributed nature of hadoop jobs the update of a salary at one place might not get reflected in the database very quickly and the data wont be consistent across all the nodes.
I think I should have also mentioned that due to the batch processing  nature, the updates wont get reflected immediately in all the nodes.
Is this final answer will be an optimal one for the question?

Comment: For me, the most important issue with a payroll system in Hadoop is data integrity.  Sure, it will be slower than most relational databases, but not being able to apply integrity constraints at the data level would kill it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, payroll is usually a batch process, howerver the question I’d rather ask is - how many employees does the company need to have in order to need hadoop to do the payroll processing.

And depending on which version of hadoop you were talking about (1.0 - pure MR based, or 2.0 with YARN):

YARN solves most of the single point of failure problems (AFAIK), on the other hand - processing payroll in a map/reduce way seems for me insane. Even more when we can assume that most of the companies (if not all of them) have this kind of data anyway stored in RDBMS.

Summarized, I’d say that MR only makes sense if the data is also stored in HDFS and there are many other and simpler ways to distribute payroll processing over multiple machines (or multiple cores - usually this should be already enough) - especially if the necessary data is stored in an RDBMS.

**Update (see comment):**

why is it insane to use MR for this job? - MR is best suited for counting words - this is not a joke. The rather surprising part is, how many problems you can solve by counting words. You can create inverted indices (MR was invented by Google, and this is what Google is doing, so it isn't surprising after all, that it is so good in it).

Spotify is for instance using MR  probably to count which song was how often listened to. You could imagine, they have gigantic logs (in text form or in Cassandra, ...) from each user listening to a song, and they need to create a report for the music labels about this, this is where MR is at its best.

I also know, about a friend of a friend, who is working (worked) in a company specializing in taking algorithms and transferring them to be executed in Hadoop as MR. This is done because of the great infrastructure of a Hadoop cluster like the management or fault tolerance.

However with YARN now many more programming paradigms can be implemented on top of a Hadoop (or YARN) cluster, not just MR. With [Apache Twill](http://twill.incubator.apache.org/) you can even deploy your own app paradigm, or just take an existing multi-threaded application modify it slightly and you can deploy it on an existing Hadoop 2.0 cluster. - With this it might even make sense to run a payroll job on a YARN cluster - provided it is necessary because you need to do it for millions of employees.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please give an example/reason why do you think map/reduce insane for you.

Comment: see the update, hope it helps - without the context of the question and some more feedback about what they wanted to hear, it's almost impossible to give one concrete answer, only a mix of bad practices when you would use it.